# Unable to sort HashTable for PHP Extension in c++

Tags: php, c++, arrays, sorting, php-extension

I'm currently stuck in developing a PHP Extension for PHP 5.6 in Visual Studio 2012.
The extension itself works and is loading in PHP, I can call the PHP functions that I created using this extension. The problem resides in the sorting an array that I receive from PHP.

using

```
if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a", &in) == FAILURE) {
     RETURN_NULL();
}
```

I get an array within my c++-function which I handle as followed:

```
HashTable *arr_hash;
HashPosition pointer;
int array_count;
char *key;
uint key_len;
ulong index;
zval **data;
zval *in;
arr_hash = Z_ARRVAL_P(in);
array_count = zend_hash_num_elements(arr_hash);

qsort(arr_hash, array_count, sizeof(int), compare);
for(
    zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer);
    zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void**) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS;
    zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer)) {
        add_next_index_zval(return_value, *data);
    }
```

the compare function that is beeing used:

```
int compare (const void * a, const void * b){
  return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

The data that this returns:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => int 1209
  1 => int 1229
  2 => int 1259
  3 => int 1219
```

Which is, as you can see, not sorted. I am a beginner with c++ and don't know how to continue from this. The strange thing is when I use the same functions but now with the following data, it works as it should:

```
long values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25 };

  int n;
  for (n=0; n<6; n++){
     php_printf ("<li>%d</li>",values[n]);
  }
  php_printf("</ul><ul>");
  qsort (values, 6, sizeof(int), compare);
  for (n=0; n<6; n++){
     php_printf ("<li>%d</li>",values[n]);
  }
php_printf("</ul>");
```

returns:

```
qsort
•40
•10
•100
•90
•20
•25

•10
•20
•25
•40
•90
•100
```

Comment: Sorting a hash table just doesn't make much sense, it's a simple ***unordered*** mapping of keys to values. If you want a sorted, or ordered, key-value mapping then a tree structure is much more suited.

Comment: Thanks for your input @JoachimPileborg! I'll look into that. However, this is the information I found on [DevZone Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/317/extension-writing-part-ii-parameters-arrays-and-zvals/#Heading5)

**Arrays:** `Since you’ve used PHP in the past, you’ve already recognized an array as a variable whose purpose is to carry around other variables. The way this is represented internally is through a structure known as a HashTable. When creating arrays to be returned to PHP, the simplest approach involves using one of the functions listed in Table 2.`

Comment: I don't know anything about the internals of PHP, but my guess is that the PHP array implementation is a mapping with the index as key and the contained element as data. The underlying hash-table is itself not ordered, but the *keys* can be stored and ordered separately. Or not at all, since the array knows its first element is index (and key) `0` and then up to the size of the array (which is also stored in the underlying data structure). Sorting an array then just swaps data around, but leave the keys.

Comment: [Continued from previous comment] And sorting a PHP is not really different from sorting an array in C or C++, you swap the elements around, but the "keys" (indexes) still stays the same. Index `0` will always be index `0`, no matter what data it "contains".